# SQL Server and .NET Typed Dataset AllowDBNull Metadata

Tags: .net, sql-server, strongly-typed-dataset

Good afternoon,

I am generating a typed dataset from a stored procedure. The stored procedure may contain something like:

```
select t1.colA, t2.colA AS t2colA 
from t1 
  inner join t2 
    on t1.key = t2.key
```

When I generate the typed dataset, the dataset knows whether t1.colA allows NULLs, but it always puts FALSE in AllowDBNull for t2.colA even if t2.colA allows NULL.

Is this because the column is aliased? Is there any way, from SQL, to hint to VS that the column allows NULL? We currently have to go in and update the column's AllowDBNull if we regenerate the table.

Thanks in advance.

Christian

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this in VS2010 with SQL2008.  I created two tables in SQL Server with null and not null columns and the designer was able to figure out their null requirements when joined in a single query.  Which versions of Visual Studio and SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think the alias must not be the cause, it's just a "rename" but the properties of the column are the same. As @Carter said, i couldn't reproduce the problem. Please give us more details.

In other way, you can avoid null values with the isnull (colum, defvalue) sentence in SQLServer but maybe you don't want it (i know it isn't "cool") because you have to get an special value that in some cases (boolean for example) could be ambiguous (so, that's the cause for using null it self).

Anyway, pleas, give us more information to help you better.

PS: Yes, bad English... Sorry I'm Spanish speaker.